# Selected tab loses its background color

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm working on WP with a purchased theme.

I have moved the navigation bar to the bottom and the problem started. The theme provides some default themes to use while creating a new page.

The problem now is that when I open a page selecting certain templates (the name of the templates are: About, Blog, Gallery, or Services), then when I select the page from the navigation it loses the background color (the one used for the selected tab). It doesn't have this issue with home page or when 'Contact' template is selected for the page.

I cannot figure out what's creating the problem.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
  <!--MENU-->
  <nav>
    <a href="#" class="menu-toggle">&nbsp;</a>
    <div class="tmenu">

    </div>
  </nav>    
  <div class="smenu clearfix"><select id="mselect"></select></div>  

    <!--SOCIAL-->       
    <div class="social">
      <ul>

        <li><a href="#" id="play_pause" title="Music">&nbsp;</a></li>

        <li>
          <a href="http://facebook.com/<?php echo get_option('source_facebook'); ?>" title="<?php echo get_option('source_facebook_tip'); ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icons/mfacebook.png" alt="" title="" />
          </a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="http://twitter.com/<?php echo get_option('source_twitter'); ?>" title="<?php echo get_option('source_twitter_tip'); ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icons/mtwitter.png" alt="" title="" />
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div> <!--FOOTER_INNER-->
</div>  <!--FOOTER-->

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
#footer {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

nav {
  display:block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.52);
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  outline:0;
  font-size:100%;
  vertical-align:baseline;
}

.tmenu {
  padding: 0;
}

a.menu-toggle:link, a.menu-toggle:visited {
  display:none;
}

.sf-vertical, .sf-vertical li {
  width: auto;
}

.menu ul li.current_page_item a {
  color: #fff !important;
  background: #ac0003 !important;
  border-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.menu ul li a:link, .menu ul li a:visited {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
  background:#ac0003;
}
```

Also here's a [link](http://topgreekgyms.gr) for the website. You can enter using 'admin123'.

Comment: show `html` code instead of `php`

Comment: @BhushanFirake It has some function related to the navigation coming through php that's the reason I kept it there. Don't you think that it might be related to the problem?

Comment: but we can't test that on our system..

Comment: your html page generated with this code...post that one

Comment: OK. I'll remove it right now.

Comment: You don't have menu with `<li>` and `<a>` on your posted html code. You have to assign class `current_page_item` to the anchor tag which haven't been assigned on other than home and contact page.

Comment: @vusan The menu is automatically generated through php that's the reason you don't see the menu. It's a wp template, so it gets the navigation for all pages through that file.

Answer (score 0):

When you click contact the list item get the class 'current-page-item'.

```
.menu ul li.current_page_item a {
color: #fff !important;
background: #ac0003 !important;
border-left: 0;
padding-left: 0;
}
```

The other list items don't get this class.
Did you create the menu by hand or did you use WP to create a custom menu?

If you did it by hand, the list items will probably not have the same event handlers.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @Raffael thanks for your response. The menu is generated through WP, so I haven't done any manual work on it. Also, the problem appears on specific templates and as the same file is used across them I cannot figure out what causes the problem.